# Ext.dataview.ListView : Disable Overscroll?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In the sencha scrollable views, like **Ext.dataview.ListView**, we can always scroll the list of elements out of the screen.

If I take this example : http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/list

Is there a way to block the list item "Alana Wiersma" ? I want this item to be with "top <= 0px".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is exactly called **overscrolling**. Try this:

```
scrollable : {
  direction: 'horizontal',
  directionLock: true,
  momentumEasing:  {
     momentum: {
       acceleration: 30,
       friction: 0.5
     },
     bounce: {
        acceleration: 0.0001,
        springTension: 0.9999,
     },
     minVelocity: 5
  },
  outOfBoundRestrictFactor: 0   
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! For some reason when applying to a List it worked but not on a Container. For any future googlers I got it working by explicitly setting the values in the initialize-             var scroller = this.getScrollable().getScroller();scroller.getMomentumEasing().y.getBounce().setAcceleration(0.0001);        scroller.getMomentumEasing().y.getBounce().setSpringTension(0.9999);            scroller.getMomentumEasing().y.getMomentum().setAcceleration(30);            scroller.getMomentumEasing().y.getMomentum().setFriction(0.5);            scroller.setOutOfBoundRestrictFactor(0)

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be to set up the scroller of the list with an initial offset

```
config:{
  scrollable:{
    direction:'vertical',
    initialOffset : {x: 0, y: VALUE}
  }
}
```

And replace VALUE with whatever value you need

Hope this helps

Comment: No, I get the same behavior, I can swipe the list over the screen.